# activity opens after crash

Tags: android, android-activity

Im making android application and i got a problem. Lets say i got 3 activities A,B,C.The problem is, when i click on OK button in activity C, it should open activity A. It opens it,but before open my application crashes. So when i click Force Close, it open my activity A.

Here is the code of button OK in activity C:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowFiles.class);  
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
}
```

Everything seems simple, but works only with crash. Help me please.

Comment: show more code . maybe manifest too . also post the logs of the crash and try to debug and see if the crash occurs in the onCreate of activity A.

Answer (score 0):

from what i can see, try being more specific with the intent. ex. MainActivity.this or make sure that all the activities are posted in your manifest.